# Passenger & Rails refuse to start up in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, production, osx-leopard

I have a production server that refuses to start up in the 'production' environment. it recently ran Rails 2.x and Passenger 1 (or 2 can't remember) just fine. Upgraded Rails & Passenger and now it starts up in the development environment even though Passenger docs say it should default to production. We haven't changed anything in its default setup.

Though I just tried adding `RailsEnv production` to the Virtual Hosts file...to no effect.

**How can I troubleshoot this?** The only output I see in the console is:

```
server:current elvis$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
```

and trying to hit app with a web browser presents [this dialog](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?198293bf49.png) after a long delay (30+ secs)

- Mac OS X Server 10.5.8
- Rails 3.0.3
- Passenger 3.0.0
- MySQL: 5.0.82

Comment: Did you look in your app's production log and your apache log?

Comment: (1) look in log/production.log. What does it say? (2) What happens if you run `rails s -e production` from the command line?

Comment: thank you! I didn't think to look at production.log for errors when it appeared, to me anyway, that Rails was running in development. i had a problem with my database.yml which I quickly fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Passenger to Nginx or Apache? You start the Rails app by running the webserver, not `rails c`. Nginx, for example, will then load the Passenger module which will run your Rails app as needed. So, startup Nginx or Apache and you should be good to go.

Comment: Apache...which is running fine on static pages. I hit the sub-URI <mydomain.com/rails> and...nothing (well, that strange Passenger error msg linked to above)